# Trying to find a specific restaurant in Jerusalem

Tags: israel, identify-this, restaurants, jerusalem

I was in Israel for the first time about 10 years ago. I have a vivid memory of that trip, in which my father took me and my sister to get real Israeli [schwarma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shawarma) for the first time and it was *sooo good*. I'd like to see if I could find this restaurant again.

Some information I remember about it:

- It's kosher (or at least it was 10 years ago)
- I'm pretty sure they have schwarma in both [pita](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pita) and [laffa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taboon_bread) (*which is very common in Jerusalem, so this won't help much*)
- I remember being fascinated by the way the store was built: it was a corner store, and had entrances at both streets. The counter was built in a diagonal, such that you could enter at one side, walk down the counter as the server filled your pita/laffa, pay and walk out the other side.
- I don't remember much about the location of the store, but I do recall flashing on the [Sbarro terrorist attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sbarro_restaurant_suicide_bombing) while waiting in line, which leads me to believe that this restaurant might be in the vicinity, and the attack was on my mind because my father told me the story when we walked past the store.
- Red color scheme on the signs? Possibly some hanging signs behind the counter?

Any help in locating this store is appreciated.

Comment: FWIW, Google Streetview has a pretty good coverage in Jerusalem. If you think your place is near the Sbarro restaurant, you might find your place if you take a virtual walk around the neighbourhood.

Comment: As interesting as this question is, isn't it highly specific to one person ?

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo I'll give it a try; thanks for the tip! :)

Comment: @Blackbird57 but isn't that also true of *any* [tag:identify-this] question?

Comment: @Shokhet quite right but I recently had a question closed for that reason

Comment: http://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurant_Review-g293983-d2676281-Reviews-Sami_s_Restaurant-Jerusalem_Jerusalem_District.html#REVIEWS Possible?

Comment: @AndrewLazarus I don't think so. It *is* a corner store, but only appears to have one entrance. Also, from the reviews it sounds like Sami's was a lot more formal than the place I remember.

Answer (score 8):

It's Melech HaFelafel on the corner of King George and Agripas. (And has been there for decades). Google Street View photo:

[image: falafel Jerusalem]

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions:

- Can you ask your father or sister if they remember the restaurant or where it was or where else you went on the tour that was nearby?
- If you are able to recall (or you father or sister can) any nearby place that you visited, you can use Google Maps to search for schwarma restaurants near that place
- You can ask in city-specific travel forums such as TripAdvisor's Jerusalem forum
- Keep in mind that the place might not still exist, or may have changed hands and not be the same now
- Keep in mind that your memory of it and how good it was may have been affected by the experience as a whole (being in a fascinating place with your family) and may have shifted over time (you might remember it as being better than you did at the time)

I do hope you discover it and that it is still open and still delicious.